# How to stop bash loop from looping over files created during the loop?

Tags: bash, loops

I want to run a loop over all files of a particular extension in a directory:

```
for i in *.bam
do
...
done
```

However, if the command that I run inside the loop creates a temporary file of the same extension, the loop tries to process this new tmp file as well. This is unwanted. So, I thought the following would solve the problem: first list all the *.bam files in the directory, save that list to a variable, and then loop over this saved list:

```
list_bam=$(for i in *.bam; do echo $i; done)

for i in $list_bam
do
...
done
```

To my surprise, this runs into the same problem! Could someone please explain the logic behind this and how to fix it so that the loop only processes the pre-existing .bam files?

Comment: `echo $list_bam`  doesnt give the list. It simply gives `*.bam`. You probably have to save the list to a file and read from it.

Comment: When I run `list_bam=$(for i in *.bam; do echo $i; done)` in my directory and then call `echo $list_bam`, I get the list of the file names.

Comment: *However, if the command that I run inside the loop creates a temporary file of the same extension, the loop tries to process this new tmp file as well.* That's impossible.

Comment: It seems impossible to me too, which is why I'm so confused.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem. An example command `for i in *.bam; do cp $i bu.$i; echo $i; sleep 0.1; done` works only for the initial files, as one would expect.

Comment: Yes, I tried your code and it works as well. Very strange... What I'm running on my bam files is a custom python script, which creates a tmp.bam in the process. I suppose the behaviour I see could be somehow caused by that script, but I cannot imagine how...

Comment: Another loop where I am unable to reproduce the problem: `rm *.bam 2>/dev/null; touch {1..5}.bam; for i in *.bam; do touch 6.bam; echo "i=$i"; done`.  It must be in the code in your loop. Can you show the code? Does the problem exists when you remove all function calls and replace the python with `touch tmp.bam`?

Comment: Thanks for your input @WalterA! It seems to be something about the python script, but I can't share it at the moment. Replacing `list_bam=$(for i in *.bam; do echo $i; done)` with `list_bam=$(ls *.bam)` seems to fix the problem, however. (Not the best way, as I see in the answers below.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop you can use find and xargs

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.bam" -print0 | \
   xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'echo "{}" > "{}.new.bam"'
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.bam" -print0 | \
   xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'echo "$1" > "$1.new.bam"' -- {}
```

example:

```
$ touch a.bam b.bam
$ ls 
a.bam  b.bam
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.bam" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'echo "{}" > "{}.new.bam"' 
$ ls
a.bam  a.bam.new.bam  b.bam  b.bam.new.bam
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement this :)

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps make sure that your globbing expression `*.bam` couldn't be interpreted afterward with something like:

```
list_bam=$(ls *.bam)

...
```

...**but**, as noticed by @glenn in the comments, this is a bad idea.
Something similar *should* be made using a `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` command template.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- `list_bam=(*.bam)` then `for bam_file in "${list_bam[@]}" ...`

Comment: Well spotted. I refined the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! This actually solved my problem for now, I will try to implement the `find ... | xargs ...` version later.